# Can we use REST API and custom templates?

Tags: api, rest

I'd like to create a website with authentication using REST framework. Well I'd not like to use it because I didn't understand everything about it, but I have to.

Can I use the REST API and yet have custom templates for administration and simple browsing ?

What I mean is that when I did the REST tutorial (on their website), I didn't see at all where I could put my templates instead of the ones generated by REST. How can I for example use the authentication of REST with my interface, my web template ?

Comment: Yes you can. I _think_ nodejs does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot figure out what do you mean by custom templates ?
Incase you want to begin with REST then you may start with jersey framework. For Security you may use OPenID or the latest OAuth2.0 specs

Here is my tutorial for REST + OAuth2.0
http://restful-fundamentals.blogspot.in/2013/02/rest-and-http.html

http://restful-fundamentals.blogspot.in/2013/04/oauth-20-introducation.html

Google code repo: http://restful-fundamentals.blogspot.in/2013/04/svn-repository-oauth20-spectifications.html